# Why would a photographer use a single head 1200 W∙s flash?

Tags: lighting, strobes, godox, power, monolights

I comprehend Godox produces a 1200 W∙s single-head flash (AD1200). But I don't have any idea why a photographer would use it.

I have a 1000 W∙s Dynalite pack, but it also takes one, two, three, or four heads.

Comment: I am not sure which direction your question aims and why it is tagged product photography. Could you elaborate? Are you interested why anyone use this flash in product photography only? Or is this a rant disguised as a question?

Comment: @KaiMattern, have a feeling the OP is ESL, and may have mistaken the product-photography tag to mean photography products, rather than photography *of* products. IMO, this is a "what is this product?" kind of question.

Comment: @inkista I agree. Hence I edited the tags of the question to point others into the right direction.

Comment: I always wished I could have one of those. With that much power you can pretty much bounce flash on pretty much any surface, e.g. light up the entire city hall or church when you shoot a wedding.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which direction your question aims at, but as a use-case for a single head high-power strobe, photos in bright daylight come to mind.

In certain scenarios using a flash to provide fill in shots against the sun, especially if you want to use a large softbox or reflex dish, you will need all the power you can get.

Also if you need to use HSS to balance ambient light in bright light with open aperture, the available power will get reduced greatly. A 600 W∙s strobe might then already be too low in output for outdoor shooting. So you have some extra wiggling space regarding power. You could of course circumvent this scenario by use of an ND filter.

Comment: There is also using HSS for fill flash along with high shutter speeds (action photography); an ND filter is not an option then. And illuminating a large area/group of people evenly... to do that requires the flash to be placed at a great distance, which eats power.

Comment: @StevenKersting Good point!

Answer (score 2):

The Godox AD1200 is a *really* different **type** of light than your Dynalite setup.

First off, it's a Li-ion battery-powered strobe.  No power cables.  So, it's really easy to take out on location, where you may need more power coming from a single head to balance against sunlight. It's also HSS and TTL capable. And having more power makes HSS for daylight fill more usable, as well as simply letting you recycle faster with lower power settings if you need to (its minimum power setting is 1/256 power).

And more power is better for bigger spread or larger distances between the light and the subject (say, for group shots or [very large subjects](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhotography/comments/f64zkd/how_to_reproduce_the_bottom_photo_many_of_my/)).

In short, it's better for location shooters.

See also the suspiciously similar question :) at: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4467769

Answer (score 0):

Some photographers (not me, so I cannot give more details) like to work with various traditional film/plate processes, which have extremely low ISO values and need ludicrous amounts of illumination to avoid motion blur with many subjects. I have seen these people preferring such powerful monolights. Using a single head is likely simply due to space or setup complexity constraints....

Comment: And large format film also typically use/need very small apertures; f/45-f/64 is very common with 4x5 film. The GN for a 1200WS strobe is around 100M (e.g. Godox QT1200ii) which means it is good for ~ 7ft subject distance at f/45 (100÷45) with the standard/supplied reflector; or ~ ≤ 2ft in a softbox *at full power* (~ 2+ stop loss).